# CSS linear gradient facing left (right to left)

Tags: javascript, html, css, linear-gradients

This should be obvious, but for whatever reason I can't figure out how to make a `linear-gradient` that faces left (using JavaScript).

```
var element = document.getElementById("log-list-id-1"); // Works, it's in another function, but definitely works.
element.style.background = "linear-gradient(right, #0000FF, #0000FF 20px, #EEEEEE 21px)";
```

I know that it works for other gradients:

```
element.style.background = "linear-gradient(#0000FF, #0000FF 20px, #EEEEEE 21px)";
```

But it doesn't work for making it face background.

*Note: I use FirefoxDevelopmentVersion 36.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to left`.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #0000FF, #0000FF 20px, #EEEEEE 21px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Using JavaScript.

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

elem.style.width = '300px';
elem.style.height = '100px';
elem.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to left, #0000FF, #0000FF 20px, #EEEEEE 21px)';
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: According to the Run code snippet, that looks like it should work - I'll try it. :)

Comment: Hmm.. the JavaScript to make it run isn't working. `element.style.background = "linear-gradient(to left, #0000FF, #0000FF 20px, #EEEEEE 21px)";`

Comment: @AquatheSeaWing - I've added a JavaScript solution as well. As you can see it works here.

Comment: @AquatheSeaWing - Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I did the exact code you put, but there are no errors in the console. By the way, I use FirefoxDevelopmentEdition 36.

Comment: @AquatheSeaWing - I need to see your entire code in order to help you.

Comment: Oh never mind! I just wasn't reloading the page right. It works now. :) Thanks!